# Что делает tie в perl

Tags: perl

Хочу переписать перловый скрипт на groovy, но столкнулся с этим

```perl
tie %IniFile, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => "$configFile" );
```

не понимаю, что делает эта функция.
Насколько я понял связывается хэш %IniFile с файлом $configFile, т.е из конфигурационного файла данные заносятся в хэш?

Comment: Да, после tie вы видите содержимое ини файла в хеше. Чтение файла происходит прозрачно для вас во время обращения к хешу

Comment: А зачем второй аргумент 'Config::IniFiles'? И как лучше сделать то же самое в groovy,  просто прочитать файл и распарсить его?

Comment: Думаю да, прочитать и распарсить или найти готовый модуль для этого. Второй параметр в tie этот как раз пакет (класс) который обрабатывает файл. https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles#USAGE-Tied-Hash  Собственно поведение связанного хеша полностью определяется этим классом. Основная идея tie в том, что бы связанная переменная могла показать произвольное поведение, определенное классом. Например есть классы которые делают прозрачный доступ к БД или скажем делают кеш, т.е. хранят не более указанного кол-ва элементов с удалением более старых

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь всё понятно!